# Get x intercept given two points

Tags: javascript, linear-regression

This might be a somewhat simple question but I can not seem to get it working.

I want to find the x intercept given two points.

Lets say I have these two points:
(5,3) and (3,4)
I would like to find the x intercept.
Currently this is what I have. Which finds the y intercept correctly. In this case 5.5.

```
var A = [5, 3];
var B = [3, 4];

function slope(a, b) {
    if (a[0] == b[0]) {
        return null;
    }

    return (b[1] - a[1]) / (b[0] - a[0]);
}

function intercept(point, slope) {
    if (slope === null) {
        // vertical line
        return point[0];
    }

    return point[1] - slope * point[0];
}

var m = slope(A, B);
console.log(m);

var b = intercept(A, m);
console.log('intercept: ' + b);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function xIntercept(a, m) {
    return a[0] - a[1] / m;
}
```

I would suggest you represent points as `{x: 5, y: 3}` instead of `[5, 3]` because it makes the rest of the code much clearer.

Comment: Bonus: How do you specify y as something else than 0?  For example if I want the x intercept where y = 20?

Comment: keep in mind that m could be zero. in that case, check a[0] if a[0]==0, then every point of the line lies on the x axis. if not, there isn't an x-intersect

Answer (score 8):

Given a straight line `y = mx + n`, it intercepts the x-axis when `y=0`.

```
0 = xm + n  --> x = -n/m
```

So the x-intercept will be `-n/m`.

Given two points `(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)`, you can find the slope and the y-intercept like this:

```
m = (y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)
n = -x_1*(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1) + y_1
```

Then, the x-intercept will be

```
x_1 - y_1*(x_2-x_1)/(y_2-y_1)
```

In JavaScript,

```
function x_intercept(a, b) {
  return a[0] - a[1]*(b[0]-a[0])/(b[1]-a[1]);
}
x_intercept([5, 3], [3, 4]); // 11
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain it by "math" instead of code, maybe this helps understanding what's behind all that:

The common equation for a straight line could be expressed as:
   *y = kx + d*

Where **k** is the slope and **d** is the y-intersect of the line.

So to calculate the x-intercept, you'd have to:

1. Check, if it's a straight line (eg. if the slope==0). If it is, the x-coordinates of your 2 given points are equal. If they are 0, then the x-intersect is the whole line. If they are not zero, there is no x-intersect.
2. Otherwise, you can obtain the y-value for the x-intersect by setting y to zero in the above equation, like this: 0 = k*x + d

Then we go on:

```
   0 = k*x + d
   0 = (-0,5)*x + 5,5
-5,5 = (-0,5)*x
  11 = x
```

To find that the x-intersect is at